# EAS build fails Task :expo-crypto:compileReleaseKotlin

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, eas

I am trying to migrate from classical builds to eas but the builds are failing due to some internal reason at Task :expo-crypto:compileReleaseKotlin

This happened with both bare and managed workflows, Expo Cli version : 5.2.0 Expo SDK Version : 44.0.0

P.S. : I dont use expo-crypto in the project, it also is not a part of package.json

Here's the error log.

```
[stderr] e: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-crypto/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/crypto/CryptoModule.kt: (10, 5): Unresolved reference: Name
[stderr] e: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-crypto/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/crypto/CryptoModule.kt: (12, 5): Interface Function does not have constructors
[stderr] e: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-crypto/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/crypto/CryptoModule.kt: (13, 5): Unresolved reference: AsyncFunction
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
333 actionable tasks: 333 executed
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':expo-crypto:compileReleaseKotlin'.
[stderr] > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
[stderr]    > Compilation error. See log for more details
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org/
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 7m 38s
```